# python 3 code incomplete output

Tags: python, output, nltk, anaconda

I am new to Python and trying to run a piece for code for self learning. In the following file, my

```
import json
import textProcess as tp

review = open('../inres_review.json')
vocabulary = open('../vocabulary.txt','wb+')
label = open('../label.txt','w+')
data = open('../data.txt','w+')

voca = []
revs = []
lab = []
dat = []
i=1

for line in review:
    jre = json.loads(line)
    jstar = jre['stars']  
    text = jre['text']  
    lab.append(jstar)
    ws = tp.removeStopPunc(text)
    revs.append(ws)
    voca += ws
    #print (i)
    i += 1

for i in lab:
    label.write(str(i)+"\n")
print ("Successfully created label !")


voca = list(set(voca))
print (len(voca))
print (type(i))
for i in voca:
    vocabulary.write(i.encode('UTF-8')+b"\n")
print ("successfully created vocabulary!")


for revid, rev in enumerate(revs):
    dat.append({})
    for w in rev:
        if w in voca:
            k = voca.index(w)+1
            if k not in dat[revid]:
                dat[revid][k] = 1
            else:
                dat[revid][k] += 1
print (len(revs))


for revid, rev in enumerate(dat):
    for k,v in rev.iteritems():
        s = str(revid+1)+' '+str(k)+' '+str(v)+'\n'
        data.write(s)
print ("successfully created data")


review.close()
vocabulary.close()
label.close()
data.close()
```

My output only displays the following :

```
successfully create label!
30346
<class 'int'>
successfully create vocabulary!
```

It isn't executing the last block therefore my data.txt file is blank too. Any comments as to why this might be happening? This code is part of sentiment analysis using nltk

Comment: Do you get any error/exception/stackstrace ?

Comment: How do you execute your script ? Standard python interpreter should print a traceback if there is an exception...

Comment: One issue that I can spot is that `rev.iteritems()` should be changed to `rev.items()`, since you indicate you're using Python 3. But the output seems to stop earlier. Though the output you pasted doesn't exactly match your code anyway (eg. "create" vs. "created").

Comment: Hi @Guillaume. I'm running the script on Jupyter notebook. It's a web editor. I've been executing codes on this editor and the interpreter has printed traceback when needed. I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: hi @lenz sorry about that. I pasted my error before and changed my script right after hence the mismatch. Fixed rev.items() but like you pointed out, output stops earlier so no change there :(

Comment: Your code prints `len(revs)` and `"successfully created data"` unconditionally; even if `revs` or other lists are empty, you should see these unless execution stops for some reason you did not report.

Comment: If all of your code is in one notebook cell, break it up into several cells so you can see what's going on.  (You can split a cell into two with a single keystroke; I think it's Control - hyphen.)

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but you don't need to write bytes to the `vocabulary` file. Open it in text mode with `open("vocabulary.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")`, and your strings will be transparently utf-8 encoded for you (e.g., `vocabulary.write(i+"\n")`).

Comment: Hi @alexis : I am actually referring to a code from github for an assignment . The original code had a print(revid+1) right before print(len(revs)). I commented that and somehow the execution stopped before that. After the comment off, command executes the entire code! I have no idea how a print statement could do that but I'm just glad the code ran. Also, I tried transparently encoding my strings the way you described and it worked! Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: A print statement can't do that. However, `data.txt` _will_ be empty if you don't close your file handle properly, e.g. if you write `data.close` instead of `data.close()`. In that case you should have seen "successfully created data" in the output stream. Maybe you did see it? You already said that you didn't report the exact output of your code, and/or the exact code that gave you the problem.